# Asp.Net Mvc Naming standard for global and Local variables and function Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want both of[Javascript & C# ] variables Naming standard for global and Local variables and function Name.

Example [javascript]:

```
var _globalVariable='test';
function clickFunction()
{
var localVariable='test';
}
```

Above the example code, i think this is not properly correct. Please give correct naming convertions.

thanks

Comment: correct in what sense ?

Comment: Is that `functiion` a typo (must be `function`)? Naming conventions are subjective; but usually using `camelCase` for entire JS/C# method arguments and `PascalCase` for class/interface/method/property names.

Comment: sorry for spell mistake..

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a standard for global and local variables.
Variables prefixed with an underscore are private variables.

```
public string GlobalVariable = "test";

function clickFunction()
{
    var localVariable = "test";
}
```

More info about the c# Coding Conventions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/C-Sharp-coding-standards-and-naming-conventions/